# WSUS Error 8000FFFF

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, windows-server-2012-r2, wsus

Two issues with our WSUS

1. Some of our Servers (2008r2/2012r2) and Win 7 got error 8000FFFF when installing security updates from WSUS. For most of servers and desktops are just working fine.
2. From WSUS report, I can see the updates have been installed on a Win 7, but when I check it manually, I dont see it from `update history` or `installed updates`.

Any idea please?

Update:

Issue fixed.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4457145/windows-7-update-kb4457145

Comment: Updated my post. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Before installing this update, install KB3177467, the last Servicing Stack Update for Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, to resolve this issue.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/servicing-stack-update-for-windows-7-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1-october-9-2018-898e4be1-168e-59e2-5536-edd55c4e7cc8

From your edit above.